# Spotipy API Rate Limiting without error response?

Tags: spotify, rate-limiting, spotipy

The Spotify API appears (?) to be rate limiting me, but without any error response

I'm using the Spotify API & spotipy in a web app, and making a lot of requests, namely using the spotipy .track() function;

`for track_id in playlist: track_info = sp.track(track_id)`

Debugging is showing me its hitting up to this function, and then getting stuck on this API call forever. I figured I hit a rate limit, but I'm used to getting 429 responses when I hit it - this time, my code's just running forever with no response.

I've tested the track() call in isolation with a valid track id, and same result.

Relatively new to this API/library and not sure about how rate limiting works or if that's even what's going on here.

EDIT: worth mentioning I can still hit other API endpoints, it is JUST this one that’s giving issue.

Comment: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/rate-limits

Answer (score 0):

Created a new app on the Spotify Developer Dashboard and got a new client id - my calls are now working. Still not sure what went wrong though, and this workaround obviously wouldn’t be practical for any app in production or with a lot of test users.